# Tmux: how do I bind function keys to commands?

Tags: tmux

How do I bind a function key (e.g. F1, which generates `ESC O P`) to a tmux command (e.g. "next window", `ctrl-B n`)?

Context: ssh running on mac into tmux session on linux.  I'm pressing `fn-F1` on the mac keyboard to generate the `ESC O P`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From the `KEY BINDINGS` section of `man tmux`:

> tmux allows a command to be bound to most keys, with or without a prefix key.  When specifying keys, most represent themselves (for example ‘A’ to ‘Z’).  Ctrl keys may be prefixed with ‘C-’ or ‘^’, and Alt (meta) with ‘M-’.  In addition, the following special key names are accepted: Up, Down, Left, Right, BSpace, BTab, DC (Delete), End, Enter, Escape, **F1 to F12**, Home, IC (Insert), NPage/PageDown/PgDn, PPage/PageUp/PgUp, Space, and Tab.
>
> ---
>
> bind-key [-cnr] [-t mode-table] [-T key-table] key command [arguments] (alias: bind)
>
> Bind key key to command.  Keys are bound in a key table.  By default (without -T), the key is bound in the prefix key table.  This table is used for keys pressed after the prefix key (for example, by default ‘c’ is bound to new-window in the prefix table, so ‘C-b c’ creates a new window).  **The root table is used for keys pressed without the prefix key: binding ‘c’ to new-window in the root table (not recommended) means a plain ‘c’ will create a new window.  -n is an alias for -T root.**  Keys may also be bound in custom key tables and the switch-client -T command used to switch to them from a key binding.  The -r flag indicates this key may repeat, see the repeat-time option.

Therefore,
`bind-key -n F1 next-window` would allow you to hit `fn-F1` on your macbook to switch to the next window in your tmux session.