# How to map a tmux command (prev,next window) to a mouse button (left,right)

Tags: tmux

I have a mouse with two additional left/right buttons, and on Ubuntu they work fine in Firefox for next/prev page in history, and in Sublime Text 3 for left/right tab (with [this .sublime-mousemap](http://perso.crans.org/besson/publis/ST3/Default%20%28Linux%29.sublime-mousemap) config file).

I would like the same kind of behavior in [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/)...

Unfortunately, I didn't find any way of mapping a tmux command (`tmux next-window`, `tmux previous-window`) to a mouse button (not left/right click or the wheel, but an other button). The manual does not evoke it, nor [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38983736/5889533) for example.

Does any one has a trick for this? Thanks.

Comment: FYI, you're not missing anything obvious, the only mouse buttons that tmux currently (2.3) supports directly are left, right, and middle. You could send a feature suggestion to the tmux mailing list, or fork the tmux repo and implement it [yourself](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=mouse&type=Code)

Comment: Hi, thanks.
I was afraid I missed something plain obvious.

I'm afraid to not be skilled enough in C to implement this myself (I quickly tried today.. not easy to dive into such C code when you aren't use to it).

I will suggest the feature to the team.

Comment: https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/588

Answer (score 0):

So [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux) (currently) [does not support](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=mouse&type=Code) these extra mouse buttons, and it [seems hard](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/588#issuecomment-254065410) to implement their support in tmux's current architecture.

Sadly, I think the only answer that can be given right now is a negative one : **it is not possible to bind a tmux command to an extra mouse button**.

Comment: Could you get the mouse button to generate an obscure key sequence and map that instead?